# Languages in XCode

Tags: xcode

I'm just about to start learning how to program using XCode. I've had Java lessons in my school for half a year now, and will continue with that for the next 2 years.

As far as I've looked into XCode, it looks like it just uses Objective C, which at my brief first sight, looks pretty different from Java syntax-wise. 
Look at C at the other hand, looks a lot more like Java.

Now I am wondering, is it possible to write iOS applications in C using XCode? It definitely would easen up my learning curve not having to learn a whole new syntax on top of a new language.

Edit: If it is indeed possible, would there be any disadvantages in using C instead of the (seems encouraged?) Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all welcome in `XCode`.

XCode is just an IDE. Now it is on you, whether you want to learn iOS or MacOS Applications.

And I would suggest you if you have a good knowlegde of C, then have some knowledge on Object oriented language like C++ or Java. Then you will feel comfortable with Objective-C.

Objective-C is a language, superset of C, so not much to think only one day learning is required to see the changeover from C to Obj-C.

And Obj-C language makes framework called "Cocoa" which is the core for ios and mac based development. This will take some time, but mind you, you will get thousands of API, which are easier to use and remember than what you will make and use from 'C'.

You can refer many sites, I would like to share my learning process with you.

---

You can follow these, even I started learning with these [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575037/what-are-resources-for-learning-objective-c/13577666#13577666).

1. Stanford lectures CS193
2. Lynda's Videos
3. Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegas
4. Cocoadevcentral.com
5. Last one is of course Stack Overflow... This is the best place to sort out all your doubts.

Comment: I'm going to focus on iOS development. I have zero knowledge of C, but I have half a year of full-study OOP and Java.
Edit: I guess I'll just jump into Objective-C. Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: If you have Java knowledge, then no problem, all looping and conditional statements are similar. In the syntax side only method passing, method declarations etc are different. Just read some basic books you will feel comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

You can effectively write most of your app in C but when you interact with the iOS SDK, the part that communicates with the device, you will need to use obj-c. Objective-c isn't hard to learn really, don't feel daunted about it.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can write code in C. Objective-C is a C language wrapped by defines.

However, I'd recommend to learn Objective-C. This allows you to write code using Object Oriented principles. There are numerous online tutorials for this.